# Dynamically assigning background image scss/sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

What I want to do is to have a form where you can upload a picture, then when you view that object, the picture cones up centered, vertically and horizontally in a specific div.  The size of it is unknown, etc.

Unless there is a way to center it vertically with the image_tag helper, I like to be able to use the image as a background image.  In my .css.scss file, I want to be able to do something like

```
.image_div {
     background-image: image_url("#{@object.image}");
     background-position: center
}
```

Im using CarrierWave to upload the pictures, and when I output @object.image it gives the path on my computer to the image (so I don't know if in production that would be considered the path or url).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's *possible* to use erb in a sass file, but it's a really, really bad idea, as your css will have to be parsed on each request (and the browser will be unable to cache it).

I'd recommend just sticking that one snippet of css directly on the view page in a style tag. That way it gets evaluated with the page. Make sense?

---

**UPDATE** (adding requested example)

Add this to your actual view (ex. show.html.erb):

```
<style media="screen">
  .image_div { background-image: url(<%= @object.image %>); }
</style>
```

You can leave the `background-position` declaration in the css file since it's not dynamic. `@object.image` needs to return the actual path to the image, so if `@object.image` is a ruby object, you'll need to access whatever property stores the path (`@object.image.path` or `@object.image.url` or whatever fits your codebase).

Comment: Inline styles on the element in question would make sense as well.

Comment: I found a solution that works - since I know the size I want it to be, I used minimagick and carrierwave to resize the picture, using gravity => center.  Although both of your options sound great, I could not get either of them to work.  Perhaps an example?

Comment: @Cade I got yours working - it won't work for : image-url('erb image_url') but it works with the standard css url('erb image_url')

Comment: @cimmanon whenever I set the display to inline on the parent div, I cant reduce the height and whenever I set the display to table-cell on the parent div, the width comes out as 1px and I can't change that.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Inline styles as in `<div class="image_div" style="background: url(filename); width: X; height: Y" />`.

Comment: @cadlac That's true. `image-url` is a helper that the [sass-rails gem](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#features) provides (see "Asset Helpers" section). With my answer, you are no longer in the context of the sass file, so the sass-rails stuff isn't available. (You only need those helpers for asset pipeline stuff anyway, which you can manage just as easily in the view.) Since it worked for you, I'd be most grateful if you accepted my answer. :)

Comment: @Cade whoops forgot, there you go! :D

Comment: There's a part of me that really dislikes this answer since it mixes the styling with the markup.  I feel like there should be a more proper way to do this...