# Rails 4 - How to use dynamic background images + have it work with rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

Is there a sane way to do dynamic background images in Rails?

I'd like to set the background image for an area of a view dynamically, based on the current database record.

I was doing this:

```
.image{ style: "background-image: url(assets/#{product.image})"}
```

But now that I've pushed to production, that doesn't work with rake assets:precompile, since that requires SASS so you can use 'asset_url' instead of just 'url'

It seems like there should be a simple solution, since I imagine it's a pretty common use case, but I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Have you ever use `carrierwave` in your application?

Comment: Where exactly are you saving/storing the images to be used as background images ?

Comment: Have you considered this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493043/dynamically-assigning-background-image-scss-sass?